# Users need to reauthenticate Per User Oauth2 Integration

Tags: integration, oauth2, namedcredentials, refresh-token

I have an AppExchange App which uses `OAuth2` `Per User` Authentication to access a 3rd Party REST API. To configure the app the Admin needs to create an `AuthProvider`, `NamedCredential` and a per User Authentication (find [detailed settings here](https://wiki.logicline.de/cleverreach/en/benutzerhandbuch/konfiguration/salesforce-sales-cloud-konfiguration#SalesforceSalesCloudKonfiguration-sf_idprovider))

**The problem: Every week or so each User needs to reauthentication using [`Authentication Settings for External System`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_authentication.htm&type=5).**

What could be the reason for this. Is this a problem of the API provider or did they forget to tell people to use OAuth `scopes` like `refresh_token`?

Answer (score 2):

Without looking into their Oauth 2.0 implementation it is hard to tell if this is a problem in the API implementation.

Also, it is important to understand what is the duration of refresh token. If the refresh token expiration is set to 7 days only then it is not good to use of refresh token. The refresh token should have an expiration of 1 year at least. For example, allows a lot of configuration options for refresh token expiration. You can read [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_manage_oauth.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

From the docs you have attached one thing is for sure is there is no refresh_token scope being added. So the issue could be simply that the refresh token scope is absent! I would request more info from API provider on this especially around their refresh token policy.

**Update:**

Reading through the documentation [here](https://rest.cleverreach.com/howto/) there is no mention of any scope for the refresh token nor the refresh token expiration policy. This should be brought to the vendor notice so they can help understand their refresh token policy.

Comment: Thanks Mohit. The App was created by our customer and I can change it but my impression is that the API provider is handling refresh tokens incorrectly. Look at their doc. They dont mention scopes they use grant types etc: https://rest.cleverreach.com/howto/#refresh_token

Comment: @RobertSösemann Yes sounds like they are not closely following the OAuth 2.0 refresh token expiration policies. You might have to talk to their engineering so they can increase refresh token timeout.

Comment: Where do you read in the doc an indication that they do something wrong. I mean they say the same to me 

Comment: https://rest.cleverreach.com/howto/. Check here, no mention of refresh token scopes and expiration. They are not doing anything wrong they just do not disclose their refresh token expiration policy :)

Comment: To be fair to Clever Reach app developers, the issue could be anywhere - on Clever side, on SF side in Named Cred, in Auth Provider, in assumptions made by various interfces, ... These types of issues should be first triaged outside of SF.

Comment: @identigral More I think, I agree but just disclosing the refresh token policy helps a lot.

Comment: @identigral: ..triaged out of Salesforce? Where do you expect the issue? Their docs describe a manual PHP OAuth which I should not do in SF. When I asked their support they alway insist on manually story the token. This is handcrafted OAuth.. But how can I proof it? From inside Salesforce.

Comment: To prove that Clever is behaving correctly, you have to do it outside of SF where you have control over client. Then do it in SF with a standard auth provider, perhaps. Then your own auth provider. In SF, you have limited control (auth provider) and even then, it gets called whenever SF wants to call it. Multi-party integration with a loose protocol (oAuth) is a complex beast, there's no Easy button.

Comment: @identigral We would have received 100s of cases refresh token flow blew in auth provider. So fairly certain it has to do with how refresh tokens expire in the Clever api

Comment: @MohithShrivastava not sure if I understand what you are saying in your last comment...

Comment: @RobertSösemann What I meant here was if this was a salesforce issue, we have 1000s of customers using auth provider setup and they would have initiated 100s of cases and we could trace it. I do not see many cases so that suggests it has less to do with salesforce being an issue.